# Wait until part of the function completes to execute the function

Tags: swift, api

I'm trying to fetch data and update core data based on the new updated API-Data.

I have this download function:

```
func download1(stock: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Quote], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
    var internalQuotes = [Quote]()
    let downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.downloadQueue")
    let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    downloadGroup.enter()
    let url = URL(string: API.quoteUrl(for: stock))!
    NetworkManager<GlobalQuoteResponse>().fetch(from: url) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err)
            downloadQueue.async {
                downloadGroup.leave()
            }
            
        case .success(let resp):
            downloadQueue.async {
                internalQuotes.append(resp.quote)
                downloadGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    
    downloadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
        completion(.success(internalQuotes))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.quotes.append(contentsOf: internalQuotes)
        }
    }
}
```

On the ContentView I try to implement an update function:

```
func updateAPI() {
    for stock in depot.aktienKatArray {
        download.download1(stock: stock.aKat_symbol ?? "") { _ in
            //
        }
        for allS in download.quotes {
            if allS.symbol == stock.aKat_symbol {
                stock.aKat_currPerShare = Double(allS.price) ?? 0
            }
        }
    }
    PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
}
```

My problem is that the for loop in the update function should only go on if the first part (download.download1) is finished with downloading the data from the API.

Comment: which for loop? Because you have 2 of them in `updateAPI()`

Comment: sorry, the for allS should only go on if the download1 is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wait! Never wait!

DispatchGroup is a good choice – however nowadays I highly recommend Swift Concurrency – but it's at the wrong place.

- `.enter()` must be called inside the loop before the asynchronous task starts
- `.leave()` must be called exactly once inside the completion handler of the asynchronous task (ensured by a `defer` statement)

I know this code won't work most likely, but I merged the two functions to the correct `DispatchGroup` workflow. I removed the custom queue because the `NetworkManager` is supposed to do its work on a custom background queue

```
func updateAPI() {
    var internalQuotes = [Quote]()
    let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    for stock in depot.aktienKatArray {
        downloadGroup.enter()
        let url = URL(string: API.quoteUrl(for: stock))!
        NetworkManager<GlobalQuoteResponse>().fetch(from: url) { result in
            defer { downloadGroup.leave() }
            switch result {
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err)
                    
                case .success(let resp):
                    internalQuotes.append(resp.quote)
                    for allS in download.quotes {
                       if allS.symbol == stock.aKat_symbol {
                       stock.aKat_currPerShare = Double(allS.price) ?? 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    downloadGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       
        self.quotes.append(contentsOf: internalQuotes)
        PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working, but I have one issue: When I run the App and click the updateAPI Button nothing happens and I get the message: "[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics" but on the second click the code works perfectly and I get the new data displayed. If i click again its also working. Just when I rerun the app I get the message and nothing is happening on the first click. On the second and third and ... click everything works. Its just the first click after rerun that doesn't work

Comment: And at irregular intervals I get decodingErrors

Comment: The `boringssl_metrics_log` warning is irrelevant and can be ignored. I just answered the question to show the proper usage of DispatchGroup. Decoding Errors and workflow issues are beyond the question.

Comment: OK thank you, I think the decoding errors have something todo with the amount of api calls per minute. But why does nothing happen on the first button click and on the other button clicks everything works fine?

Comment: I have no clue. There is no code related to a button or to display data in the question. Please ask a new one and add the necessary code.